# Golang Sort :does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len method)

Tags: sorting, go

I´m having issues implementing the Sort interface in my Go app. Here´s the relevant code:

```
type Group struct {
   Teams []*Team
}

type Team struct {
    Points int
 }

    type Teams []*Team

            func (slice Teams) Len() int {
                return len(slice)
            }

            func (slice Teams) Less(i, j int) bool {
                return slice[i].Points < slice[j].Points
            }

            func (slice Teams) Swap(i, j int) {
                slice[i], slice[j] = slice[j], slice[i]
            }
```

So I wanna sort the groups´ teams on based on their points. But whenever I run

```
sort.Sort(group.Teams)
```

I get this error:

```
 cannot use group.Teams (type []*Team) as type sort.Interface in argument
to sort.Sort:   []*Team does not implement sort.Interface (missing Len
method)
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[]*Team` is not the same as `Teams`; you need to explicitly use or cast to the latter:

```
type Group struct {
   Teams Teams
}
sort.Sort(group.Teams)
```

Or:

```
type Group struct {
   Teams []*Team
}
sort.Sort(Teams(group.Teams))
```